# Integral, u substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

This problem is giving me a headache.

$$ \int \frac {4/7 + \sqrt{x\sqrt{x}}} {\sqrt{4-x(1+x^{3/4})}} \,dx $$

I tried simplifying the x's but im still lost.

$$ \int \frac {4/7 + x^{3/4}} {\sqrt{4-x-x^{7/4}}} \, dx $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $$ \int \frac {\color{blue}{\bf{\large\frac 47 + x^{3/4}}}} {\sqrt{\bf{4-x-x^{7/4}}}}\,dx $$

Let  $\bf{u=4-x-x^{7/4}}\,$:

$$du = -1 - \dfrac{7}{4}x^{\large \frac 34}\,dx \implies \;\;\color{blue}{\bf-\frac{4}{7}\,du \;= \;\frac 47 + x^{3/4}\,dx}$$

You should end up with 
$$\color{blue}{\bf-\frac{4}{7}}\int\frac{\color{blue}{\bf{du}}}{\sqrt{\bf{u}}}$$

after substituting.

Comment: At the first sight, one cannot guess what is happening in the integrand. +1

Comment: @Babak Yeah, the integrand sure looks messy; it looks more complicated than it turns out to be!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Substitute $u=4-x-x^{7/4}$, then we get
$$-\frac{4}{7}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} du.$$